# My textarea text isn't styling the way that i would like it to CSS with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like the text in the textarea to start off grey and turn to black after text has been entered.  the text wont start off grey but if i click on it then off then on again it will be grey.

HTML code

```
<li class="message">
<textarea name="message" id="message_input" rows="4" cols="25" maxlength="200"
            onfocus="if(this.value=='Add additional information here!') 
            {this.value='';this.style.color='#000';}" 
            onblur="if(this.value=='') {
            this.value='Add additional information here!';this.style.color='#999';}"
            >Add additional information here!</textarea>
</li>
```

CSS code

```
li.message {
    position: absolute;
    top:255px;
    left: 150px;
    color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the textbox, not the LI

```
li.message textarea {     
    color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize jQuery to more easily manipulate the DOM, see this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CVrx/) example where I am changing the text color depending on focus() and blur().

```
<li class="message">
    <textarea name="message" id="message_input" rows="4" cols="25" maxlength="200">Add additional information here!</textarea>
</li>

li.message {
    position: absolute;
    top:255px;
    left: 150px;
    list-style: none;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#message_input').focus(function(){ $(this).css('color','gray'); });
    $('#message_input').blur(function(){ $(this).css('color','black'); });
});
```

Comment: When posting answers make sure you include your code. Fiddle's don't last forever and we want future visitors to benefit from your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try and avoid inline javascript declarations. It is also better to use classes to manage your style changes. Even this could be improved upon as I would like to see the default value stored and checked instead of checking the string each time. `classList` is not supported by IE7, but there are workaround if you must support it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bTRgz/1/

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('message_input');
textarea.onfocus = function() {
    if (this.value == 'Add additional information here!') {
        this.value = '';
        this.classList.add('active');
    }
};

textarea.onblur = function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = 'Add additional information here!';
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
}
```